# Nvidia 5200 graphic card active but not currently in use

Tags: 11.04, drivers, upgrade, nvidia

Nvidia 5200 graphic  card active but not currently in use on Ubuntu 11.04  how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by active but not currently used? Can you explain further or provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

It is [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/704014). If you can run `nvidia-settings` and that shows that you are using the nvidia driver, then you can safely ignore the "not currently in use" warning.